# Run Cucumber Features in Parallel using parallel_tests gem

Tags: selenium, parallel-processing, cucumber, capybara

I am using Selenium locally to run two .feature files.  Both pass locally.  Neither of the tests interact with a db (nor will future tests).  I would like to use the parallel_tests gem to spin up two selenium web browsers concurrently and run each .feature file.  I have tried to follow the readme on gems homepage, but am still having no luck.

I can run `rake parallel:features` and I get the following output:

`Using recorded test runtime`

`8 processes for 2 features, ~ 0 features per process`

However, it then proceeds to fail immediately and informs me that I have not defined the scenarios.

I am using Rails 3.2 and Capybara

I have also tried adding `begin; require 'parallel_tests/tasks'; rescue LoadError; end`
to the top of my Rakefile which I found elsewhere, but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 parallel_cucumber -n 2 features
```